# How can I delete a folder or file with path too long in recycle bin?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the program that deletes and copies some folders or files with long path (when lenght > MAX_PATH) In this program I use the prefix `\\?\` that gives me the possibility delete folders or files with long path but only in simple function `Delete()`. I need to delete files in Recycle Bin and for this I need use the `SHFileOperation` function that gives me possibility delete files in the recycle bin, but this function does not support the prefix `\\?\` . Can anybody help me with this issue?

Is there some alternative for SHFileOperation. 
How can I bypass this problem?

Some links:

- [Prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) `\\?\`
- Some about [Long Path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx)
- [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recycle bin is a special shell folder. It is part of the shell. The shell however has the limitation that paths must not be longer than MAX_PATH. So the same limitation applies to the recycle bin.

You simply can not put files/folders with long paths in the recycle bin. Not possible.

Edit: Windows 10 has the MAX_PATH limit lifted. See [this msdn entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)

Comment: The shell seems to be able to do it, when I perform the delete from explorer...